# JAR file I created runs only on computers with JDK installed

Tags: java, netbeans, java-8, jar

I recently created an application using the NetBeans IDE. I deployed it and created a jar file that runs perfectly on my computer and any computer that has the Java JDK installed, but when I try to run it on another computer that only has the JRE installed it says:

"Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again"
and then
"A Java Exception has occurred."

Comment: add java exception stack trace to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have JDK that you used to create jar with version1 and jre with version2 then you will encounter this kind of error.

For example:
If i used Java JDK 12 installed on my computer#1 to create jar.
At the same time, I had Java 8 (JRE) Installed on my friends computer.
So on my friend's computer it is not working because it has jre8..

I typed the follow commands to troubleshoot :
On computer#1 :

```
javac -version
```

// this gave me Java 12

On computer#2

```
java -version
```

// this gave me Java 8

In other words, my program is getting compiled with Java 12 (computer1)and I am trying to run with Java 8 on computer2.

To solve the problem, try running jar on same version of java used for development. Means match jdk and jre version.

Comment: Thank You! I spent hours trying to fix it not knowing this.